# Rails – Custom Resource Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to customize my show route... I don't want users to be able to view items by :id...

I have a sales model, and the show route is:

```
sale GET    /sales/:id(.:format)     sales#show
```

But, I don't want users to be able to view sales by id, instead, I'd like it to be:

```
sale GET    /sales/:guid(.:format)     sales#show
```

The guid is a uuid I generate when the object is created:

```
def populate_guid
    self.guid = SecureRandom.uuid()
end
```

Comment: What is `:guid`, some alternate id?

Comment: It's a UUID I'm generating (added more info to original post)

Answer (score 11):

In config/routes.rb

```
get '/sales/:guid', to: 'sales#show'
```

or if you use rails 4 you may:

```
resources :sales, param: :guid
```

In controller

```
def show
  @sale = Sale.find(params[:guid])
end
```

Comment: I love the rails 4 way! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom route in your routes.rb:

```
get "/sales/:guid", :to => "sales#show"
```

And then in your controller, for the show action, you find the sale you want from the `guid` that was passed in the url:

```
def show
  @sale = Sale.find_by_guid(params[:guid])
end
```